# Want to extract data from 1 file and write it to 50 files in python

Tags: python, loops, parsing, iterator

I want to extract 4 constant columns from a file, and then get a further 'variable' column and write this to a file. I then need this to loop 50 times. So in each of the 50 files there is a different 'variable column'. I have the chunk of code to do this once, but I need to write a loop in order to get the information i need into the 50 files. Here is the code i have:

```
os.makedirs("new_dir")
directory = os.path.realpath(__file__)
run = directory.split('/')[4]
my_file = open('file_i_am_using.txt', 'r+')
sample = my_file.readline().split('\t')

outputfiles = []
for i in range(51):
    output = 'output%i.txt' %i
    outputfiles.append(open('new_dir/'+output, 'w'))

for line in my_file:
    column = line.split('\t')
    lst = column[1:3]
    lst.insert(2,column[i])
    lst.insert(3,sample[i])
    lst.insert(4,run)
    lst.insert(5,'\n')
    outputfiles[i].write('\t'.join(lst))

for i in range(51):
    outputfiles[i].close()
```

At the moment this saves the 50th file with the information required. How can I get the information into the other files? I have tried writing a loop before the 'for line in my_file:' line, but i don't know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Well, during the writing loop, you're never incrementing `i`.

Comment: Oh ok. But when I add 'for i in range(51):' before the 'for line in my_file' line it just adds the information i need to the first file made, and the other files are completely empty?

Comment: Your spacing is wrong. Use nested loops

Comment: Yes I'm sorry that was a mistake... when 'for i in range(51): is added before the second loop (and this correctly indented), it just adds the information to the first file, and the rest are empty

Answer (score 0):

use nested loops like this and with keyword to simplify dealing with files:

```
import os
os.makedirs("new_dir")
directory = os.path.realpath(__file__)
run = directory.split('/')[4]

with open('myfile.txt', 'r+') as my_file:
        sample = my_file.readline().split('\t')

for i in range(51):
    output = 'output%i.txt' %i
    print(output)
    with open('myfile.txt', 'r+') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            column = line.split('\t')
            lst = column[1:3]
            lst.insert(2,column[i])
            lst.insert(3,sample[i])
            lst.insert(4,run)
            lst.insert(5,'\n')
            with open('new_dir/'+output, 'w') as out:
                out.write('\t'.join(lst))
```

but can't test on your data as you haven't provided it !

Comment: I have tried this, however it just adds the information to the first file, and the rest are empty? I do not understand why

Comment: can you add a small sample input file to check ?

Comment: i have improved my answer but still not tested on your data as i don't have it

Answer (score 0):

'i' is incremented to 50 after the first loop; and then not reset to start before second loop. That is why it is saving just in the last file since i=50. In the last loop, all files are safely closed, but the write happened to only last file from second last loop. You can do:

```
for i in range(51):
    output = 'output%i.txt' %i
    outputfiles.append(open('new_dir/'+output, 'w'))
for line in my_file:
        column = line.split('\t')
        lst = column[1:3]
        lst.insert(2,column[i])
        lst.insert(3,sample[i])
        lst.insert(4,run)
        lst.insert(5,'\n')
        for i in range(51):
             outputfiles[i].write('\t'.join(lst))
```